# Firebase Authentication Security: Making email+password errors generic

Tags: firebase, security, authentication, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I've made a page that allows sign in using Firebase. But our tester is raising a security concern about adding too much information in these messages - we want to have a generic error instead ("Invalid email or password") rather than saying "Invalid email" and "Invalid password" to prevent malicious parties knowing which emails are registered. Is there any ways to change the errors generated from the Firebase system?

Comment: Sorry, i was hoping someone else would have a way, but I'll.accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the error messages generated by Firebase. The only way to control messages that the user sees while still using Firebase Authentication would be [create your own custom provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) and then raise messages from there.

You might want to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for this, although there's no guarantee it will be implemented in a timeframe that suits your project.